# Are Higgs rumours increasing the traffic in physics websites, particularly SE?

Tags: discussion

This is sort of meta, so here it is: Have admins noticed, in the last three weeks, an increasing of traffic into StackExchange coming from searches for higgs related topics? And a subtopic of it, could be, is there an increase on specific searches (say "two photon decay") from research institutions as cern.ch, .edu, etc?

Note that google [trends](http://trends.google.com/trends?q=higgs,%20LHC,%20lepton,%20dilepton,%20cern&ctab=0&geo=all&date=mtd&sort=0) and [insights](http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=higgs,%20LHC,cern,%20dilepton,higgs%20boson&date=today%201-m&cmpt=q) are already detecting the news impact of the rumours; I would expect that the details of search engine hits into physics websites will have more detail, perhaps even some searches with "xxx GeVs" or "yyy channel".

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! We (moderators) don't have access to traffic information in enough detail to determine whether the Higgs search is increasing traffic, but my best impression is that any such increase for this site at least is fairly small. In the list of searches that we get hits from, anything relating to the Higgs is pretty far down the list, and besides, the overall traffic level for the site has been pretty steady, or *slowly* growing, over the past several months.

One way we can get a bigger piece of the action is to increase the number of questions on the site that relate to the Higgs boson. So if you have any ideas, ask away!